# How to create a heart rate detection system that uses a chest strap?

Tags: sensors

I want to create a system that uses a chest strap from available Bluetooth-based heart rate monitoring systems. The straps seem very convenient compared to available Arduino pulse detection systems that use electrode pads (which must be placed individually and that wear out), or infrared sensors, which are cumbersome.

I find the Bluetooth systems not super reliable and would like to use the strap with a wired Arduino based system. Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: You're asking how to create a wired connection to an unspecified device not designed for it. You'll at very least need to specify the device.

Comment: You'll need a data-sheet (or other spec) for the sensors in the particular strap, and from that, buld an interface to your Arduino. It will probably involve supplying power to the sensor, amplifying the sensor output, noise rejection (low-pass filtering might be enough), detecting the signal exceeding a threshold, and outputing a level or a pulse when it does.

Comment: I can manage detecting a pulse from a signal. The strap is from a Polar H7. The battery is a CR 2025 which is 3V. Can the Arduino 3.3V supply power to the sensor? How could the output be amplified and the noise reduced? Is this post, http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=317073.0, relevent?

Comment: I think that the correct answer is yes/no. Theoretically you can, if you have the appropriate knowledge. Dismantle the sensor, and probably you will find that there is a battery, a circuit and some wires going to some electrodes. Detach the wires from the circuit, and use them exactly like you would use some standard electrodes. But when I built a small ECG I bought the electrode pads because other materials have a very high contact resistance, and so I think that the main problem with your band is the electrodes (consequently even with an arduino you will get poor performances)